# Finding modular inverse of $x^4$ in $GF(2^5)\mod (x^5+x^2+1)$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, finite-fields, euclidean-algorithm

I cannot spot where I am going wrong in this. I am using Extended Euclidean's algorithm here.

$(x^5+x^2+1) = (x^4)(x) + (x^2+1)$

$(x^4) = (x^2+1)(x^2+1) + 1$

let $P(x)=x^4$ and $Q(x)=x^5+x^2+1$

$(x^5+x^2+1) + (x^4)(x) = (x^2+1)$

$(x^4) + (x^2+1)(x^2+1) = 1$

$P(x)+[Q(x)+P(x)(x)][Q(x)+P(x)(x)]=1$

$P(x)(1+xQ(x)+P(x)x^2+xQ(x)) +Q(x)(...)=1$

$P(x)(1+P(x)x^2)+Q(x)(...)=1$

$P(x)(1+x^6) + Q(x)(...)=1$

$(1+x^6) \bmod (x^5+x^2+1)=x^3+x+1$

I am getting the inverse of $x^4 \mod (x^5+x^2+1)$ as $x^3+x+1$ but it seems the right answer is $x^4+x^2+1$. Can anyone tell me where it is wrong?

Comment: I find the same final result as you. If you found the answer in a book, it happens there are typos.

Comment: You are right. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Your answer is correct. For a different way: The multiplicative group of $GF(2^5)$ is cyclic of order $2^5-1=31$. Therefore the inverse of $x^4$ is $x^{-4}=x^{31-4}=x^{27}$. Repeated squaring (or a CAS) quickly tells that 
$$x^{27}\equiv x^3+x+1\pmod{x^5+x^2+1}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct since, taking into account that the characteristic of the field is $2$, so that $x^5=x^2+1$,
\begin{align}
 x^4(x^3+x+1)&=x^7+x^5+x^4=x^7+x^4+x^2+1 \\
&=x^2\cdot x^5+x^4+x^2+1=\color{red}{\not x^4}+\color{blue}{\not x^2}+\color{red}{\not x^4}+\color{blue}{\not x^2}+1\\
&=1.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you. The answer is indeed correct.

Answer (score 0):

We want to solve $$x^4 \cdot (c_0 + c_1 x + c_2 x^2 + c_3 x^4) = 1$$

multiplying this out gives

\begin{align}
& c_0 x^4 + c_1 x^5 + c_2 x^6 + c_3 x^8 \\
=&\, c_0 x^4 + c_1 (x^2 + 1) + c_2 (x^3 + x) + c_3 (x^3 + x^2) \\
=&\, c_1 + (c_1 + c_3) x^2 + (c_2 + c_3) x^3 + c_0 x^4 \\
\end{align}

so we want to solve the linear system:

- $c_1 = 1$
- $c_1 + c_3 = 0$
- $c_2 + c_3 = 0$
- $c_0 = 0$

to get our inverse $x + x^2 + x^3$

Comment: The idea is good. But you forgot one term. Try $c_0+c_1x+c_2x^2+c_3x^3+c_4x^4$. This is a degree five extension field so you need five coordinates rather than four.

Comment: Thank you for the correction!